# SQL Server DB that was created in Visual Studio won't open in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I just created a sql server compact database as part of a MVC3 project using the code first technique in conjunction with the Entity Framework. This was a success and I can connect to this new database via Visual Studio. However when I try and connect to the same database using Sql Server Management Studio I run into problems. This is the Error I get:

[image]

Can anyone tell me what I need to do in order to make the connection?

the following is the code from my webconfig file that was used to create the database:

```
<add name="PetrolPriceDBContext"
     connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|PetrolPrices.sdf"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
```

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 Mgmt Studio doesn't support SQL Server Compact **4.0** (only up to v3.5) - for that, you need SQL Server **2012** Mgmt Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot open SQL Server Compact 4** files with **SSMS 2008 R2**, **only 3.5 files**.

You can use Visual Studio 2010 SP1 + VS Tools for SQL CE 4 (installed via WepPI)

Check [**ErikEJ Blog Pots**](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/12/visual-studio-tools-for-sql-server.html)

Here are some 3 rd party Tools [**Here**](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2009/04/sql-compact-3rd-party-tools.html)

Answer (score 0):

Per marc_s comment, here is a link to the official download you need:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062

Choose SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe or SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe

---

I generally just use ErikEJ's SQL Server Compact Toolbox for SSCE4 work.

http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/

[Visual Studio add-in version](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1/)